# Using "at about" for approximations

Tags: prepositions

> The material is processed in the autoclave **at about** 150 degrees Centigrade.

My question relates to the usage of 'at about' to indicate approximate temperature rather than the exact temperature

Comment: Yes, you can say “at about” to indicate an approximate amount. Is your question just whether this is valid grammar? It is.

Comment: Hi @Esb Rao and welcome to the site. Can you please clarify exactly what question you are asking? Are you asking "can I use this contruction" or "what does this construction mean", etc? We can guess, but it is better if we know for sure.

Comment: My question is meant to seek clarification of the grammatical correctness of the construction of this sentence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ***about*** is used to indicate approximation. It is used correctly in your example. If you were being precise, you would say "at 150 degrees"; *about* is inserted immediately before the measurement, after *at*.